# XSL 1.0 Summing values with £, " and , in whist using a key

Tags: xml, sum, xslt-1.0

I am trying to sum the following costs grouped by a unique field called ID

The xml is as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>"£20,000.00"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>"£1,000.00"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>"-£2,000.00"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>"£2,000.00"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>"£1,000.00"</td>
</tr>
```

I have produced the following which keeps returning NAN due to the non numeric characters.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:key name="UniqueJobNumber" match="table/tr" use="td[01]"/>
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:for-each select="tr[(count(. | key('UniqueJobNumber', td[01])[1]) = 1)]">
        <xsl:variable name= "PaymentRequestValue" select="sum(key('UniqueJobNumber',td[01])/td[02])"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="td[01]"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$PaymentRequestValue"/>
        <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone know a way of removing the £, and " characters from the field to make the sum work?  I have tried using translate functions within the variable used to calculate the value but that doesn't seem to work.

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use, do you have access to `exslt:node-set`? In that case I would suggest to use a two step transformation where the first step removes the characters like double quote, pound symbol and comma from the number values and the second then uses your approach to compute the sums.

Comment: I don't think you can use sum() here (at least not directly). I would call a recursive processing template to translate out the currency symbol and add the resulting number to the total.

Comment: I do not have access to exslt:node-set unfortunately.  Any suggestions or solutions that can be provided would be great.  The XSLT 1.0 processor is built into a software application for transforming outbound and inbound files so I'm not sure what processor is used.  Thanks so far.

Comment: "*The XSLT 1.0 processor is built into a software application for transforming outbound and inbound files so I'm not sure what processor is used.*" You can find out by including `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>` in your stylesheet. "*I do not have access to exslt:node-set*" How did you determine that? I don't know of any XSLT 1.0 processor that does not support this function.

Comment: Presumably you are using XSLT 1.0, because if you were using 2.0 the answer would be trivial? Please clearly label XSLT 1.0 questions using the appropriate tag, otherwise people can waste a lot of time answering them.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know a way of removing the £, and " characters from the
>   field to make the sum work?

<del>You need to do this one-by-one. Try something like:</del>

**EDIT:** I have replaced the previous template by a more generic one. Instead of **removing** unwanted characters, this one **keeps** only characters that are valid for a number-type value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<total>
    <xsl:call-template name="total">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="table/tr/td[2]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</total>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="total">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($nodes)">
        <xsl:variable name="num" select="translate($nodes[1], translate($nodes[1], '-.0123456789', ''), '')" />
            <xsl:call-template name="total">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $num"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```